# NSRange strange behavior

Tags: ios, nsrange

I have strange NSRange behavior on my device (iPhone iOS 4.3). This code has a different behavior on device and simulator.

```
for (Location *location in locationArray)
{
    NSRange range1 = [location.name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange range2 = [location.streetAddress rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange range3 = [location.postalCode rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (range.length1 > 0 | range2.length > 0 | range3.length > 0)
    [self.filteredList addObject:location];
}
```

If some of properties has nil value range.lenght for that property is equal to 2 on device and zero in simulator.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html)

> The value returned from a message to
>   nil may also be valid:
>
> - If the method returns an object, then
>     a message sent to nil returns 0 (nil).
>     For example: Person *motherInLaw =
>     [[aPerson spouse] mother]; If the
>     spouse object here is nil, then mother
>     is sent to nil and the method returns
>     nil.
> - If the method returns any pointer
>     type, any integer scalar of size less
>     than or equal to sizeof(void*), a
>     float, a double, a long double, or a
>     long long, then a message sent to nil
>     returns 0.
> - **If the method returns a
>     struct, as defined by the Mac OS X ABI
>     Function Call Guide to be returned in
>     registers, then a message sent to nil
>     returns 0.0 for every field in the
>     struct. Other struct data types will
>     not be filled with zeros**.
> - If the
>     method returns anything other than the
>     aforementioned value types, the return
>     value of a message sent to nil is
>     undefined.

It's for Mac OS X but I think it's safe to say that you should not rely on returned struct values if message target is nil.